# SASS install path on MAC OS

Tags: emacs, sass

### Problem description:

I am using Emacs scss-mode on Macbook Air, the problem is when I save *.scss file , it said: can not find the SASS command.

I can run SASS command in the terminal (I installed by sudo gem install sass). But where is the SASS executable command path, so I can update my .emacs file accordingly?

I searched ~/.gem/ , /usr/lib/gem/ directory, but failed to find sass.  Now I just disabled scss compilation function , but it's really inconvenient.

---

So I find sass using "find".

Change to .emacs is as below:

1. Add sass PATH to emacs PATH:

(setenv "PATH"
  (concat
    "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.6/bin" ":"
   (getenv "PATH")
  )
)

2. And because I use "compass" also, I add below compile options to make sure everything is fine when C-x C-s is clicked.

(setq scss-sass-options '("--compass"))

Comment: On my macbookAir it was at /usr/bin/local

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1**:  The original poster should use a search utility to search his *entire* hard drive for the executable "sass".  On Snow Leopard, for example, it installs to `/usr/bin`, but may not necessarily be in the same place for the original poster.

**STEP 2**:  The original poster should look at line 40 of `scss-mode`, which can be adjusted to use an absolute path if the original poster would prefer not to fiddle around with the Emacs $PATH -- see https://github.com/antonj/scss-mode/blob/master/scss-mode.el

---

The following command can be used to see the current $PATH used by Emacs:

```
M-x eval-expression RET (getenv "PATH") RET
```

Once the location of "sass" has been located, the original poster can add it to the Emacs path if needed -- e.g.,

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/path/to/folder-containing-sass"))
```

---

See also the instructions on the first page of the `sass-mode` repository for additional setup ideas:

https://github.com/antonj/scss-mode

Comment: If his terminal can find the executable but not emacs, you can simply add the path containing sass to the `exec-path` variable so you don't have to modify $PATH.

If you're on OSX this problem can usually be solved by using the `exec-path-from-shell` package.

Comment: Thanks! I find the path:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.6/bin/